# Space between agents in discrete-event simulation

Tags: anylogic

I have a question about space between agents. In my model I have agents generated from a source and then they enter a delay, after the delay the agents go into a a queue with a capacity of 1 but I have a preemption option. The agents that go into the preemption are supposed to move along a circled path (I used a delay block for this) but there should always be a certain space between the agents, e.g. 100 meters. How can I incorporate this in my model to make sure my agents are not too close to each other?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way you can control the distance between your agents is to move them on a path using a dummy transporter instead of the moveTo block. Transporters allow you to define a minimum distance to obstacle that prevents the agents from getting too close to each other.

Answer (score 1):

Two options if you mean the static queue with agents actually waiting:

1) if your queue size is 500 meters, define the maximum amount of agents allowed in that queue to 6 (so you have 100 meters of distance between each agent)

2) Use the PML settings block from the PML palette and define an initial capacity of animation location equal to 6 (if your queues are 500 meters)... but this applies to all the model, so maybe it won't be good enough.

If you want them to have 100 meters space while they are moving towards their objective through the path that represents the queue, then the answer depends heavily on your model and it cannot be answered with the info provided... you need in this case to control the agent movements adding some logic... but I don't know what logic is suitable for you.